# What is the best number of PWM signals for Full-Bridge driving? (2 vs 4)

Tags: pwm, full-bridge

Full-Bridge resonant converter circuit:

[image]

Each transistor (Mosfet) has its own driver ([ISO5852S](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/iso5852s.pdf?HQS=dis-mous-null-mousermode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1608636769113&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Feu.mouser.com%252F)).

I assumed that a full bridge could be controlled with two PWMs.

```
PWM1A, PWM1B, PWM2A, PWM2B.
```

Each PWM, at its own time step, drives two transistors.

The driver has both inverted and non-inverted inputs, so we can protect the system from through-current in the event of a PWM failure.

I have also seen circuits where 4 separate PWMs are used to control the FULL-Bridge. (PWM1, PWM2, PWM3, PWM4), with A, B outputs for each.

It turns out that in the case of 2 PWMs, only two groups of transistors can be controlled separately.
And in the case of 4 PWMs - each transistor separately.

**Question:**

1. Why are 4 PWMs used instead of 2 to control Full-Bridge?
2. What does the separate control of each transistor give?

Comment: Dead band, phase shift ability, flexibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why are 4 PWMs used instead of 2 to control Full-Bridge?

Phase Shifted PWM (PS-PWM) control,Space Vector Modulation (three phase)..., other kinds of switching sequence to those you have in mind.

> What does the separate control of each transistor give?

HiZ control, adjustable dead time on driving side,...

Your app. can be a quasi resonant LLC converter, driven with PS-PWM.